# MySQL on AIX operating system

Tags: mysql

I could see any proper documentation which answer these questions

1.Is MySQL database and cluster supported on AIX operating system?

2.Is MySQL database and cluster free for commercial use in any private enterprise application ?

Comment: Not really a programming question. MySql can be compiled from source on AIX, but it isn't easy. (Not only it is written in C++, but it uses cmake too.)

Comment: A note: a header in MySql-5.5.38 source has this line (activates only if symbol `_AIX` is defined): `inline double my_ulonglong2double(unsigned long long A) { return (double A); }` Now you can guess how much time it has been compiled on Aix. (When you have fixed this and a few other platform specific problems, it does compile.)

Comment: try to read this link http://www.systemscanaix.com/blog/your-first-hour-with-mysql-on-aix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html the answer is no, AIX is not a supported operating system for MySQL database however you can install it through `yum`, for information on how to install `yum` on AIX refer to https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/alpha.html

Concerning support you should address this with MySQL Technical Support (ref. https://www.mysql.com/support/) as they are the ones who would ultimately need to decide if they will provide support for your installation, which they may refuse on the basis that you are not operating their product on an officially supported / certified operating system. Concerning pricing, no, MySQL for commercial purposes is not free (ref. https://www.mysql.com/products/).

Comment: With all that said, in the case of errors, it's not hard to `mysqldump` and import the data in a `MySQL` database operating in a supported environment to eliminate the possibility of the error being directly related to the underlying operating system, e.g. if the error can be reproduced in a supported environment then there's no reason in my opinion that MySQL Technical Support wouldn't assist you with that error.

Comment: @whoever that downvoted, without an explanation as to why(?) I don't see how this answer can be enhanced, e.g. is nonconstructive.